# move a windows OS partition to another partition of the same size

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I want to move my windows partition to another drive that is already partitioned (including a 100 mb partition at the start of the disk and a partition of the same size as the original windows partition).

Making a system restore image (using the official windows tools) doesn't let me select a partition and I don't want to re-install my other operating system on the other partitions.
Is it possible to just move it the the new partition and fix the boot errors using a windows repair disk??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option would be to use a cloning software to clone the one drive over to the other (Something like norton ghost or [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) would do it).

After the cloning operation is done you can expand the partition to fit the entire size of the disk using computer management -> then disk management tools in the control panel.

AFAIK you can't use a windows repair disk to do this.

Comment: I know I can do this but I don't want the partition to use the entire disk but just that one partition of the same size as the original

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I understand the question then. So you want the new hard drive to have the same partition size as the old one?

Comment: I want to move my windows partition to a partition on another disk of the same size. the problem is that the new partition isn't at the same location on the disk and a windows image or a disk clone tool doesn't allow me to move the content of the old partition to the new partition.

Comment: That won't work. You can't copy a partition *into* a partition. You can only move the *contents* of a partition into a partition, and that's not a good idea with a windows installation as permissions may get messed up in the move and will probably leave you with a unbootable system.

Comment: That's probably the best way to do it. If you use a clone tool you can move the location and size of the partition after the fact too. food for thought.